# "Illegal Choice has been detected"

Tags: forms

I am dynamically populating `<select>` throught javascript in Drupal 7. The system gives me an error on submit:

"Illegal Choice has been detected"

How to mark, that this `<select>` must skip this error?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To solve the problem set '#validated' => 'TRUE' in your form element definition.

```
Example:
 form['my_dynamic_select'] = array(
 … 
 '#type' => 'select',
 '#validated' => TRUE
 …
 )
```

Reason:

If we are using a dynamically populated SELECT (dropdown) via AJAX this error will pop up. When a value is not present in options array, Drupal will consider it as illegal. So the user couldn't inject an illegal value into the database.

But in our case it's totally ok, so we need to use the attribute `'validated' => TRUE` to skip the validation.

Source: [An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator](http://drupaldummies.blogspot.ru/2012/01/solved-illegal-choice-has-been-detected.html).

Comment: This did not work for me though, diving deep into code, it says if !isset(#validated) then run the validations, but didnt work for my case though ...

Comment: This works for me in conjunction with `$form['dynamic_field']['#webform_validated'] = TRUE`

Comment: @Teknotica Thank you, you can edit the answer if you wish.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! Same issue, fixed now after putting '#validated' => TRUE

Answer (score 3):

You need to do it on the server side, using a [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) function and the [`#limit_validation_errors`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#limit_validation_errors) property of the Form API. You'll need to tweak it to suit your own needs but the following should help:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'my_form') {
    $form['submit']['#limit_validation_errors'] = array();
  }
}
```

Be wary that the above will ignore *all* validation errors on the form. You'll need to put the names of the form elements that you *do* want to be validated in the `#limit_validation_errors` array.

Comment: Keep in mind that "The #limit_validation_errors property is ignored if submit handlers will run, but the element doesn't have a #submit property, because it's too large a security risk to have any invalid user input when executing form-level submit handlers." Source: L1399 https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/_form_validate/7