# select2widget: An illegal choice has been detected

Tags: 7, forms

I am trying to use latest select2.js (4.0.1) with drupal select2widget module. As per select2 documentation I have changed the "select2widget_field_widget_form" for "select2widgetajax" option  from "hidden" to "select list" field as follows-

```
case 'entityreference':
      $options=array();
      foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
          dsm($value);
          $uid = $value['target_id'];
             $user = user_load($uid);
             $user_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);
             $options[$uid] = $user_wrapper->field_full_name->value();

         }

    // Check original field configuration
    if (!empty($instance['field_mode']) && !empty($form_state['field'][$field['field_name']][LANGUAGE_NONE]['instance']['widget']['type'])
      && $form_state['field'][$field['field_name']][LANGUAGE_NONE]['instance']['widget']['type'] == 'og_complex') {
      $autocomplete_path .= '?field_mode=' . $instance['field_mode'];
    }



    $default_value = _options_storage_to_form($items, $options, $value_key, $properties);

  $element += array(
    '#type' => 'select',

    '#default_value' => $default_value, 
    // Do not display a 'multiple' select box if there is only one option.
    '#multiple' => TRUE  ,
    '#options' =>  $options,
    '#process' => array('select2widget_entity_process_callback', 'ajax_process_form'),
    '#value_key' => $value_key,
    '#settings' => $instance['widget']['settings'],
    '#element_validate' =>  array('select2widget_field_widget_validate'),
    '#properties' => $properties,
     '#autocomplete_path' => $autocomplete_path, 
  );
  break;
}
```

Everything works fine. Select2 is populated perfectly and I can select from the list also. But when I want to save the form it is throughing the    error like:

> An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.

After doing some google I came to know that if we are using a dynamically populated SELECT (dropdown) via AJAX this error will pop up. When a value is not present in options array, Drupal will consider it as illegal. So the user couldn't inject an illegal value into the database.

I've tried this solution as explained [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31846/illegal-choice-has-been-detected?newreg=829fa6bb45fb47c9bb2d4a39d6a5f2f8) and added:

```
$element['#validated'] = TRUE;
```

in my field_widget_form. But no luck.

Comment: If you are using any other Ajax function other than #autocomplete_path then try to recreate the whole element again in that function and return form.